# Syntax trees for sentences

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees

I am having trouble drawing a syntax tree for 3 sentences and I would appreciate it if someone could help me.

The sentences are:

1. This giraffe reads books about psychopharmacology.
2. Monarchs will fly to Mexico.
3. The computer said that a fatal error occurred.

I would also be thankful if you can explain to me how to draw them, because I do not understand them very well.

Comment: What syntactic theory? GB? MP? HPSG? Something else?

Comment: looks like LIN101 or Intro. to Syntax.

Comment: Why are you asking here? Is it an assignment you were supposed to do by yourself? I'm not sure if you should be asking such questions in the first place. And I'm not sure if it's a good idea to encourage it here.

Comment: @prash I think the issue here is a bit more complex than it seems. First of all, this is the OP's first question, so I think that even if we could ask for some effort from the OP on questions like this one, we could go easy on new users and provide some help. Second, the OP asked also about some guidance about how syntax trees should be done, so I don't think this is a "gimme teh codez" question. If you wish to discuss about this matter, consider posting a Meta question, so we can discuss on it. :)

Comment: @prash as a teaching assistant, I think it shows effort if the student goes online and engages in a forum, even if they are just asking for the answer to their homework. half of the students don't bother and just get the homework wrong and then resent the professor when they fail the test, so i think it's good if they ask for help on homework, however they do it.

Comment: @Alenanno: [Done](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/313/111) :-)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about help with particular syntax trees.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sentences are parsed as follows:

1. **This giraffe reads books about psychopharmacology.**

   [image]
2. **Monarchs will fly to Mexico.**

   [image]
3. **The computer said that a fatal error occurred.**

   [image]

The trees have been made in the site [phpSyntaxTree](http://ironcreek.net/phpsyntaxtree/?).

What is a tree?

> A tree is a mathematical object consisting of a set of points called
> nodes between which certain relations hold. The nodes correspond to
> syntactic units; left-right order on the page corresponds to temporal
> order of utterance between them; and upward connecting lines represent
> the relation ‘is an immediate subpart of’. Nodes are labeled to show
> categories of phrases and words, such as noun phrase (NP); preposition
> phrase (PP); and verb phrase (VP). ([Scholz et al 2011](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/linguistics/))

Comment: I inserted the trees. It's not a problem if the answer is too long. This way it's easier to see them. :)

Comment: ... don't forget LFG-trees :) *remembers* maan I'm rusty

Comment: Thank you very much to the person who posted the trees.  I actually tried myself to find software for such trees, but it seems like I do not understand very well how they work.  Thank you again!!

Comment: I do think I'd've put an NP node between VP₁ and S₂ in the third one. S₂ is in fact operating as an object NP in VP₁, and that's fairly important to the syntax. Other than that minor cavil, though, well done. Thank you.

Comment: @Visitor If this answer helped you, remember to accept it! :) [Click on the √ symbol under the upvote/downvote buttons](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, and I'm not entirely sure about the PP and the DetP (could be DP that splits into 'this' and NP 'giraffe'), it should rather look like this (using Redford's structure)

[image]

(I used http://mshang.ca/syntree/ to draw the tree.)

Comment: In terms of the bracketing, as far as i can make out this is more-or-less equivalent to the answer previously given, only the more standard X'-theory notation (Jackendoff, 1977) has been used. The substantive difference is the introduction of a tense/inflection node, which is indeed a better analysis - as it allows us to draw parallels between sentences with finite verbs and sentences with auxiliaries. In this instance, the tense morphology lowers from I to V.

As for DPs vs. NPs, in vast majority of recent lit., NP is embedded in a DP across the board, following Abney (1987).